# Coordinating Client and Server side Ports (TCP/IP)

Tags: lan, tcp, ports

I recently started experimenting with TCP/IP in Java (question not Java specific), and I was wondering if there was a work-around to this problem: I want my Client to be able to list all available Local Network servers. This is easy when every server and client use the same port, eg. 48,000 - just cycle through every possible IP and ping any existing servers...

But what if a user already had a game open that was using port 48,000? The game would just crash with no work around. A fix would be for the server to loop and test every port between say 48,000 and 60,000, but then how would the client know which port to connect to?

I want to be able to list all available servers (like a game such as Halo does), without the user having to specify a port number.

Thanks for the help

Comment: where is your coding effort?

Comment: +manetsus I thought this question would be broader than just 1 language, like a specific algorithm or method to solve

Comment: @Taj Perhaps if you provided the relevant portion of the Java source code, the problem would be more easily understood. Although the code would be Java code, it would still be understandable for those who don't know the language.